# Is there any recent changes in the win32wnet library that anyone observed?

Tags: python, windows, winapi, pywin32

I have been using this library win32wnet.WNetGetUniversalName to validate directory/file paths on the shared drive. it was working as intended until I observed now that if I pass '\\xyz\Model(M:)\Test' (xyz is storage device name), it does not work anymore and gives following error: (1200, 'WNetGetUniversalName (for buffer size)', 'The specified device name is invalid.')

It still works if I just pass 'M:\Test' with out keeping full names.

win32wnet.WNetGetUniversalName('\\xyz\Model\Test', 1) -- this does not work
win32wnet.WNetGetUniversalName('M:\Test', 1) -- this works

Can someone please assist if you know about any fix?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32/commits/main/win32/src/win32wnet/win32wnet.cpp

Answer (score 0):

*PyWin32* homepage: [[GitHub]: mhammond/pywin32 - pywin32](https://github.com/mhammond/pywin32).

You'd have to be waaay more specific when saying "recent".

But considering that:

1. [[MS.Docs]: WNetGetUniversalNameW function (winnetwk.h)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winnetwk/nf-winnetwk-wnetgetuniversalnamew) (***emphasis*** is mine) states:

   > The **WNetGetUniversalName** function ***takes a drive-based path for a network resource*** and returns an information structure that contains a more universal form of the name.
2. Using the following script and a network drive mapped to a local share, *PyWin32* behavior is consistent across versions:

   *code00.py*:

   ```py
   #!/usr/bin/env python

   import os
   import platform
   import sys

   import win32wnet as wwnet

   # @TODO - cfati: Original script altered in order to work with ancient Python versions

   def main(*argv):
       print("%s\n" % (platform.platform(),))
       spdir = None
       for d in sys.path:
           if d.endswith("site-packages"):
               spdir = d
               break
       if spdir and os.path.isdir(spdir):
           verf = os.path.join(spdir, "pywin32.version.txt")
           if os.path.isfile(verf):
               print("PyWin32 version: %s\n" % (open(verf).read().strip(),))

       path = r"y:\dummy"
       res = wwnet.WNetGetUniversalName(path, 2)
       print("Universal name for '%s': %s" % (path, res))
       if res:
           wwnet.WNetGetUniversalName(res[0], 2)


   if __name__ == "__main__":
       print("Python %s on %s\n" % (" ".join(elem.strip() for elem in sys.version.split("\n")), sys.platform))
       rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
       print("\nDone.")
       sys.exit(rc)
   ```

   - Actual (at answer time):

     > ```
     > [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q073391922]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.09_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
     > Python 3.9.9 (tags/v3.9.9:ccb0e6a, Nov 15 2021, 18:08:50) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
     >
     > Windows-10-10.0.19044-SP0
     >
     > PyWin32 version: 304
     >
     > Universal name for 'y:\dummy': ('\\\\CFATI-5510-0\\share_public\\dummy', '\\\\CFATI-5510-0\\share_public', '\\dummy')
     > Traceback (most recent call last):
     >   File "e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q073391922\code00.py", line 32, in <module>
     >     rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
     >   File "e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q073391922\code00.py", line 27, in main
     >     wwnet.WNetGetUniversalName(res[0], 2)
     > pywintypes.error: (1200, 'WNetGetUniversalName (for buffer size)', 'The specified device name is invalid.')
     > ```
   - Older (2019):

     > ```
     > [cfati@CFATI-5510-0:e:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q073391922]> "e:\Work\Dev\VEnvs\py_pc064_03.05.04_test0\Scripts\python.exe" ./code00.py
     > Python 3.5.4 (v3.5.4:3f56838, Aug  8 2017, 02:17:05) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
     >
     > Windows-10-10.0.19041-SP0
     >
     > PyWin32 version: 227
     >
     > Universal name for 'y:\dummy': ('\\\\CFATI-5510-0\\share_public\\dummy', '\\\\CFATI-5510-0\\share_public', '\\dummy')
     > Traceback (most recent call last):
     >   File "./code00.py", line 32, in <module>
     >     rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
     >   File "./code00.py", line 27, in main
     >     wwnet.WNetGetUniversalName(res[0], 2)
     > pywintypes.error: (1200, 'WNetGetUniversalName (for buffer size)', 'The specified device name is invalid.')
     > ```
   - Ancient (a *Python **2.4.4*** build from **2008** with whatever *PyWin32* version was available at that time):

     > ```
     > C:\Work\Dev\StackOverflow\q073391922>c:\Work\Dev\Py\py_pc032_020404\python.exe ./code00.py
     > Python 2.4.4 (#71, May 14 2008, 14:40:36) [MSC v.1400 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
     >
     > Windows-XP-5.1.2600-SP3
     >
     > Universal name for 'y:\dummy': ('\\\\127.0.0.1\\share_public\\dummy', '\\\\127.0.0.1\\share_public', '\\dummy')
     > Traceback (most recent call last):
     >   File "./code00.py", line 32, in ?
     >     rc = main(*sys.argv[1:])
     >   File "./code00.py", line 27, in main
     >     wwnet.WNetGetUniversalName(res[0], 2)
     > pywintypes.error: (1200, 'WNetGetUniversalName (for buffer size)', 'The specified device name is invalid.')
     > ```

one can only conclude that you made a confusion and **it never worked** (not *OOTB* at least) as you claim it did. 
Probably you are referring to another function (possibly from another module)?